# Determinate the number of significant digits

Tags: numbers, digits

How can I determinate the number of significant digits of a double type number given by user.

Thank you.

Comment: How did the user give the number? Type in decimals?

Comment: Yes the user gives it with filling a fielld. So first the number is given on string type.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a string, then count the number of characters after the decimal using a string iterator while omitting leading or trailing zeroes.

Comment: This method counts the number of decimal places, not the number of significant digits.

Comment: True, but it's almost there - just convert to string, remove the decimal point and the trailing zeroes and the string length will be the number of significant figures +1 because I would have taken a lot longer to get there without this answer.